# Push Down Automata

Tags: logic, automata

I've been stuck on this one problem for a couple of days now with no clue on how to complete it.

> Construct a PDA which accepts precisely the language
>   $\{a^{2n} (bc)^n\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

If anyone can help. I would be eternally indebted

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, do you know how to construct a PDA for $a^nb^n$? If you have one for $a^nb^n$ and one for $a^nc^n$, what can you do with that?

Comment: _Hint:_ Have you noticed that $a^{2n}=(aa)^n$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Stack *a*mber plates as they arrive. When a *b*lue plate comes in followed by a *c(hartreuse plate, unstack two amber plates. Throw a tantrum if the amber plates don’t arrive in pairs, or the blue and chartreuse plates don’t alternate properly.